# Getting errors when installing iPython 5.0 for python 2.7 on windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ipython

I am trying to install IPython 5.0 for python 2.7 on Windows 10 using pip like this in cmd propmpt:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install IPython==5.0
```

But its failing and showing some error which I dont know how to resolve.Error:

> Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\vishal\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-sfsbeq\scandir\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\vishal\appdata\local\temp\pip-auxpgu-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vishal\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-sfsbeq\scandir\

Previously I have installed other packages such as numpy using pip command and it worked fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same error here. Looking forward to some solution.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at the answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498495/error-when-installing-using-pip).

---

I'm trying to install iPython on windows, too. The difference is that I'm targeting the newest version (no matter which). I met with **the same error**, but before it I got **another message**:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

Just download and install the package mentioned above, and retry

```
pip install ipython
```

Hooray!