# How do I resolve this pip error for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the `textract` module on Mac.

I used these commands to try and install it.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install textract   
python3 -m pip install textract
pip3 install textract
sudo pip3 install textract
```

I use `pip3` since I have multiple versions of python installed on my device.

Every time, I get the following error:

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
-u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-ejk7ayox/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /private/tmp/pip-record-o8jq5l_l/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-ejk7ayox/pocketsphinx/
```

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498495/error-when-installing-using-pip), I tried:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip3 install -U setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
```

Pip and setup tools are both up to date and I still get the error.

Comment: Try to create a virtualenv, activate it and `pip install textract`.

Comment: I tried that: `Command "/Users/One/python-virtual-environments/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-6okrc438/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-l3zuyz25/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/One/python-virtual-environments/env/include/site/python3.7/pocketsphinx" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-6okrc438/pocketsphinx/`

Comment: On my Ubuntu I can't reproduce the issue :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions in [textract - installation](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html):

```
brew cask install xquartz
brew install poppler antiword unrtf tesseract swig
pip install textract
```

I am able to install textract on my Mac.